# Upgrading to CiviCRM 4.63 from 4.4x on current Joomla 3.x

Tags: joomla, upgrade

The upgrade went fine - the DBs script ran with no errors --

Can view contacts, members, past events just fine

When I go to try to manage event - I get the errors below - I also get issues when I try to use a contribution page (same error) and I can not initiate a new mailing - I just get a page with the civi headers on it but no mailing content. (image attached for clarity) 
[image] 
Thoughts and thanks

editing an event error
Database Error Code: Unknown column 'filters' in 'field list', 1054
Additional Details:
Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Au2Kz.png) => handle
        )

```
[code] => -19
[message] => DB Error: no such field
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] =>
```

SELECT  id,
    code,
    description,
    amount,
    amount_type,
    events,
    pricesets,
    memberships,
    autodiscount,
    expire_on,
    active_on,
    is_active,
    discount_msg_enabled,
    discount_msg,
    count_use,
    count_max,
    filters
  FROM cividiscount_item i
  WHERE is_active = 1
  AND (count_max = 0 OR count_max > count_use)
 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'filters' in 'field list']
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => 
  SELECT  id,
    code,
    description,
    amount,
    amount_type,
    events,
    pricesets,
    memberships,
    autodiscount,
    expire_on,
    active_on,
    is_active,
    discount_msg_enabled,
    discount_msg,
    count_use,
    count_max,
    filters
  FROM cividiscount_item i
  WHERE is_active = 1
  AND (count_max = 0 OR count_max > count_use)
 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'filters' in 'field list']
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such field" code=-19 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="
  SELECT  id,
    code,
    description,
    amount,
    amount_type,
    events,
    pricesets,
    memberships,
    autodiscount,
    expire_on,
    active_on,
    is_active,
    discount_msg_enabled,
    discount_msg,
    count_use,
    count_max,
    filters
  FROM cividiscount_item i
  WHERE is_active = 1
  AND (count_max = 0 OR count_max > count_use)
 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'filters' in 'field list']"]
)

Comment: Lobo - turns out I did not run the update on CiviDiscount - now membership and event existing pages work I am still getting the no content when clicking on new mailing and when trying to edit existing event location I get Network Error
Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Can u disable the cividiscount module. Seems like that module is responsible for the above error.

Comment: Lobo - turns out I did not run the update on CiviDiscount - now membership and event existing pages work

I am still getting the no content when clicking on new mailing and when trying to edit existing event location I get Network Error Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again.

Comment: this is the current error [Mon May 25 13:05:26 2015] [warn] [client 89.66.xxx.xxx] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method CRM_Core_BAO_UFGroup::getCreateLinks() in /mnt/data/vhosts/casite-582819.cloudaccess.net/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Resources.php on line 676

Comment: @Josh - the new issue is a second question; please open a new question for it. You'll get more attention, it's less confusing, and it's very difficult to read an error message that's not formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Brian at icdservices.biz who found one other extension that needed up be updated in order for 4.6.3 to work -- everything is fine now.

Thanks